# Tradingview subscription about PineScript Indicator

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

My current PineScript publish settings are **Privacy Setting** is **Public** and **Visibility** is **Protected**.

What will happen if I didn't renew the Tradingview subscription?
Can everybody see the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, everything will remain as they are. You will not have your additional privalages anymore.